# Making listview scrollable to fit only a portion of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to fit my listview to be scrollable only to a portion of the screen,i have few other design to be shown in the bottom of the screen ,below is my code where in i have added layout-weight=1 has per other posts.I have already referred other posts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" Computer Languages..." />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ListView android:layout_height="200dp"  Change the list view height in dp. It depends on how much size you want to be covered by lisview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

**EDIT:** Below is your layout file with changes made to the ListView and, as a test, I added a TextView, which should force the ListView to give it the space it wants. If you test this layout in an emulator, on a phone, or preview it in Eclipse / AS, it does exactly what's expected.

If this layout is not working properly for you, then there's something else at play here, maybe you're modifying the layout programatically, but without additional info/code to see, I can't say.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" Computer Languages..." />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="test test text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight="1"` will fill the screen. should use less than 1 as per requirement because weightSum is not defined.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i have tried adding weight but its not working out for me

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yes, it will fill the screen -- minus any elements above or below it. It's exactly what the OP wants. WeightSum doesn't factor into this scenario.

Comment: @sarah when you added layout_weight, did you also change layout_height to 0dp, as shown in my example above?

Comment: @mjp66 yes i tried :( it is fitting my entire screen

Comment: @sarah I updated the answer with an example TextView , which causes the ListView to give it enough space to be displayed.

Comment: @mjp66 i have an issue about the same,the after displaying listview i am displaying comment section which goes to the bottom of the screen leaving more space after listview has such not able to add other layouts after comments section ,same code is used

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...
 >
<TextView 
 android:id="@+id/firstview"
 ...
 />
 <ListView
  android:layout_below="@+id/firstview"
  android:layout_above="@+id/lastview"
 ...
 />
  <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/lastView"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add your views below ListView on the same level in the same LinearLayout. That said, you might want to set `layout_height="0dp"` in the ListView (so that its height doesn't need to be measured one extra time), which results in improved performance. This is especially useful with ListView items. As long as you keep the other views' layout_weights unset (or set them to 0), your ListView takes up all the remaining space.